# Get Font Vectors

Tags: javascript, fonts, frontend, vector-graphics

I'm trying to play around with the silhouette of fonts in Javascript, but I can't go forward without being able to get the vectors from the characters.  Is there any way to retrieve this information and use it?  Any examples of this being done?

[Paper.JS](http://paperjs.org/) seems like it could be pretty handy but I haven't found any font examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct way to retrieve shapes from characters in JavaScript. I suspect that is because font rendering is not done directly by the browser. This task is usually delegated to a third party library like cario.

You could create the text in an SVG editor such as [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/), convert the text to paths (`Path` → `Object to Path`) and manipulate them via JavaScript.

Using [SVG Fonts](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/fonts.html) also seems like a way to go. This is basically an SVG file that saves the shapes of all characters. You could load this as XML into a HTML/JavaScript setup and process the character shapes from there. [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) has a generator for making @font-face kits. It also includes an SVG version of the font in the archive.